# Submenu disconnect on mouseover and cant navigate to submenu as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to create a submenu, but had to keep the submenu `HTML` out of the main menu, and on mouseover it will show hide, but its not working as expected, I think I am not trying with a good approach, can someone look in to this and suggest.

Here is the [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g9Lx8rb1/)

**Notes**
1. Problem is, when you mouseover on "Shop" and try to enter submenu, its hiding.
2. I had to keep the submenu html out of the main navigation as submenu has to be in full width.
3. I am also looking to add some transition effects, I know using display none/block, transition will not work but can somebody please suggest?

```js
$('.shop').mouseenter(function(){
      $('.primary-subnav').show()                        
  }).mouseleave(function(){
      $('.primary-subnav').hide()
 });
```

```css
.nav{float:left; width:100%;}
.primarynav {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: right;
}
.primarynav > li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
}
.primarynav > li > a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #333;
 padding: 0 15px;
 height: 67px;
 line-height: 67px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
.primarynav > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #c0e5da;
}
.primary-subnav {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 64px;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 2px solid #c0e5da;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
 min-height: 350px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="primarynav">
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="shop">Shop</a> </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a> </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a> </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="primary-subnav">
  <div class="container"> Submenu Wrapper </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "not working as expected", what is expected?

Comment: when I mouseover on Shop, I should be able to navigation to submenu div, that red block..currently when you mouseover and try to enter submenu, it will hide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attach the same event handlers as you have attached to mouseover and mouseleave events of `.shop` to `.primary-subnav`.

```js
$('.shop').mouseover(function(){
      $('.primary-subnav').fadeIn(1000);                        
  }).mouseleave(function(){
      $('.primary-subnav').hide();
 });
$('.primary-subnav').mouseover(function(){
      $('.primary-subnav').show();
  }).mouseleave(function(){
      $('.primary-subnav').hide();
 });
```

```css
.nav{float:left; width:100%;}
.primarynav {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: right;
}
.primarynav > li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
}
.primarynav > li > a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #333;
 padding: 0 15px;
 height: 67px;
 line-height: 67px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
.primarynav > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #c0e5da;
}
.primary-subnav {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 64px;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 2px solid #c0e5da;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
 min-height: 350px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="primarynav">
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="shop">Shop</a> </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a> </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a> </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Nav Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="primary-subnav">
  <div class="container"> Submenu Wrapper </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, this solved the issues, is there anyway keeping the main menu active when are in submenu?

Comment: you can make an active class and add that to the button in main menu from mouseover event of submenu

Comment: Yes got it, add class and remove class on mouseover event has done it. Thanks for answer!!